# adding space in html

Tags: html

I would like to know if its possible to add a space inside the table? 
This is my code: I want to have a space between "Copy the Anti-spam code" and the box where the code appears.
How could you do that? 
Thanks

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td><label for="name">Name:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" size="60" maxlength="60" eform="Name::1" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><label for="firstName">First Name:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="firstName" size="60" maxlength="60" eform="First Name::1" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Copy the anti-spam code:<br/><img src="[+verimageurl+]" alt="verification code" border="1"/></td>
    <td valign="top"><input type="text" name="vericode" size="20" />
</tr>

<tr>
    <td rowspan="2" valign="right">
        <input align="right" type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
    </td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: &nbsp;  would not work for you?

Comment: @mplungjan: i tried it but all the boxes where you write your info move to the right. I would like to have the spam code to move downward a little bit

Comment: @KennyTM: you mean i should put "valign="bottom"?

Comment: we don't know what you need to put there, but `right` is not a valid value for `valign` in any case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you mean vertical space, seeing as there is a line break?

Options:

1) wrap the "Copy the Anti-Spam code" text into a `label class="antispam"` and give that `label` a `padding-bottom` value

2) give the image a `class="antispam"` and give that class a `margin-top` value

Update: example.

In the head:

```
<style type="text/css">

   img.antispam { margin-top: 16px }      

</style>
```

In the markup:

```
<img class="antispam" src="[+verimageurl+]" alt="verification code" border="1"/>
```

Comment: can you please give me an example for this? I don't know where to add this one?

Answer (score 3):

Do you me the image with "the box where the code"?

"Space" is usually created with `margin` in CSS:

```
<img src="[+verimageurl+]" alt="verification code" border="1" style="margin-top: 2em;"/>
```

Consider moving the style to your external stylesheet.

Comment: +1 to you and Pekka. I can't believe the amount of answers that doesn't involve CSS.

Comment: yes, did you see that box, where the code changes all the time? just above the "word"register?. That's what i mean, i would like to move it a little downward if its possible, but the &nbsp is not working

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty

```
...
<tr>
    <td>Copy the anti-spam code:<br/><img src="[+verimageurl+]" alt="verification code" border="1"/></td>
    <td valign="top"><input type="text" name="vericode" size="20" />
</tr>

<tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>

<tr>
    <td rowspan="2" valign="right">
        <input align="right" type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
    </td>
</tr>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
<td>Copy the anti-spam code:&nbsp;&nbsp;<br/><img src="[+verimageurl+]" alt="verification code" border="1"/></td>
```

Or do you mean this?

```
<td>Copy the anti-spam code:&nbsp;&nbsp;<br/><br/><img src="[+verimageurl+]" alt="verification code" border="1"/></td>
```

Comment: ok but this one, this only moves the textbox to the right, but the box where the spam code appears. I would like to have the spamcode box to move down a little bit. is that possible?

Comment: Yes, remove the nbsp and either use the two br's or if that is too much, add a margin to the image using CSS

Answer (score 0):

You could use `&nbsp;` to put a space in, or maybe use a transparent 1x1 pixel image and stretch that to the size you require/